# Using event to get two values from textfield

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, actionlistener, jtextfield

I just want the `actionPerformed` event method to be used once. For example: I'm trying to get two values from one textfield.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
     String whatever = tf.getText();
     if(whatever.equalsIgnoreCase("good"){
     inout.append("blahh");
     //and then I'm trying to get a new value from the user without it resetting.
}
```

Comment: Without what resetting? How is the user supposed to supply the new value?

Comment: I think we're going to need more context before we can help you.  Do you have a runnable example?

Comment: without the actionPerformed method running again. I want to use the .getText() method again but can't because it is using what was already entered for the new value

Comment: after the comments i want to add:

Comment: String whatever2 = tf.getText(); //and this is the same value but I want it to use the new entered text

Comment: I believe what you are saying is once the program takes a value from that event the event cannot happen again correct? are you using a button to make the event happen?

Comment: yes. I am using both a JTextField as well as a button

Comment: is there any way i can get additional text from the text field after the user presses enter once?

Comment: @user2632230: do you want clear textfield and add new text to it after button press?

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to retrieve two strings but that's not possible because every time the enterbutton is pressed the method restarts

Comment: @user2632230 added explanation to my answer to make sure it sticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to make the same event execute two actions then you could try the following:

```
int choice = 0;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
    if ( choice == 0 ) {
        String whatever = tf.getText();
        if(whatever.equalsIgnoreCase("good"){
        inout.append("blahh");
        ...
        choice++;
    }// end first action
    else if ( choice == 1 ) {
        //Second action
        //Your code for what happens the second time would go here
        choice++;
    } else {
        //you can do this forever
    } 
}
```

As a new programmer you should understand why this works:

There is endless posibility for code. By seeing this you should note that you can incorperate many of the loops, switches, and other statements you've used leading up to this. In this case I'm making a condition choice that changes what happens when you click your JButton.

When you get better you will learn about threads and Events, that in essence are threads built into Java, and you will be able to do a lot more.

Keep up the good work and never give up on a hard problem :D.

Comment: To be more specific I am trying to create a program where a user inputs a string and if the user inputs good or whatever the program would respond and ask a question and expect another response. This is not possible with just one event method, I believe

Comment: @user2632230 You can write nearly anything you want to the Event. You just need to code it. Are you trying to call another method when the event is called again?

Comment: kind of. I want the user to be able to enter one string and then enter another without having another textfield or button. The main problem is the event. Whats wrong: if the user presses enter, a value is stored no problem. But when the user responds to that question and presses enter, the whole actionPerformed method is called again

Comment: Here's what i mean: public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
  
  String whatever = tf.getText();
  inout.append(newline + whatever);
  if(whatever.equalsIgnoreCase("good")){
   inout.append("blahhh");
   String ok = tf.getText(); //this value is the same as String whatever. That's the problem.
   
   
   
   
  }
 
 }

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe the answer was this easy, sometimes I guess I just forget the basics ha.